# WebRequest on Xamarin.forms with AD authentication

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, webrequest

Well, the problem is this. I´m trying to do a WebRequest to a service that uses AD authentication.

```
CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

request.Method = "POST";
request.Timeout = 5000;
request.ContentLength = 0;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.CookieContainer = cookies;

CredentialCache cc = new CredentialCache();
cc.Add(new Uri(host), "NTLM", new NetworkCredential(usr, password, domain));
request.Credentials = cc;
```

There is no problems with the authentication... at least at the first time. The problem is that if i connect a first time with an user and password of the domain A (for example), later it is imposible to me to change this user for another one (B, for example). It is always using the same user and password even when i changed for others and always is logging in with the same credentials. It´s look like something is saving the credentials and using the same ones all the time but i don´t know how it does.

On the other hand, i also tested this code in a desktop platform (C# and VS) and it works fine. It´s only in xamarin when it doesn´t work.

I hope i having expressed myself good enough. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please check `Control Panel->User Accounts->Credential Manager` to see if the username and password are cached there?

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have said this before. I am using this code in an android application with xamarin. On a windows platform it does not give me any problem. That's when I use it on android when it fails.